# use function or class of scala in spark: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: scala, class, apache-spark

I just started studying scala and spark. Got a problem about function and class of scala here:

My environment is scala, spark, linux, vm virtualbox. In Terminator, I define a class:

```
scala> class MyClass extends Serializable {
     |   val field = "Hello"
     |   def doStuff(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = { rdd.map(x => field + x) }
     | }
var a=new MyClass
aaa=sc.textFile("data.txt")
```

where data.txt is very simple:

```
1 2 3 4
a b c d
```

when I try a.doStuff(aaa), I got the following error information:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at     org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
....
```

I tried some ways that I found online. Just cannot get it work.
Anyone can help? Many thinks.
Because I am a beginner, please give me as many as details if this is a big trouble. Otherwise, I might be still confused. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post your full spark graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot I somehow figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is ok:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

scala> class MyClass extends Serializable {
     | val field = "Hello"
     | def doStuff(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = { rdd.map(x => field + x) }
     | }
defined class MyClass

scala> val a=new MyClass
a: MyClass = $iwC$$iwC$MyClass@2d4fe03b

scala> val aaa = sc.textFile("/home/fengchen/mine/sparkexamples/data.txt")
aaa: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /home/fengchen/mine/sparkexamples/data.txt MapPartitionsRDD[12] at textFile at <console>:30

scala> a.doStuff(aaa).collect
res12: Array[String] = Array(Hello1 2 3 4, Helloa b c d)
```